# Scss specific style for multiple classes using "&"

Tags: css, sass

I've got this Scss:

```
.top {
    background-color: red;

    &--checked {
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    &--completed {
        background-color: green;
    }
}
```

Which compiles correctly to this:

```
.top {
    background-color: red;
}
.top--checked {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.top--completed {
    background-color: green;
}
```

This is probably simple, but I'm trying to add an additional style for elements using both "top--checked" and "top--completed", but nested within top.

Something like this (in CSS):

```
.top--checked.top--completed {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

I'm just not sure on how to achieve this, as chaining ampersands doesn't seem to produce the desired effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best you can do would be something like this:

```
&--checked#{&}--completed {
  background: blue;
}
```